# Is there any undocumented z-order magic for drawing road casings?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

According to the [Mapbox-GL Style Spec](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#root-layers), layers are drawn in the order specified by the `"layers"` array of the style json. Let's assume a subset of the [bright-v8](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles/blob/v2.0.2/styles/bright-v8.json) style with just four layers to get secondary/tertiary roads and bridges with casings:

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "name": "Bright",
  "metadata": {
    "mapbox:autocomposite": true,
    "mapbox:groups": {
      "1444849345966.4436": {
        "name": "Roads",
        "collapsed": true
      },
      "1444849334699.1902": {
        "name": "Bridges",
        "collapsed": true
      }
    }
  },
  "sources": {
    "mapbox": {
      "url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7",
      "type": "vector"
    }
  },
  "sprite": "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/bright-v8",
  "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  "layers": [
    {
      "interactive": true,
      "layout": {
        "line-cap": "round",
        "line-join": "round",
        "visibility": "visible"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "mapbox:group": "1444849345966.4436"
      },
      "filter": [
        "all",
        [
          "in",
          "class",
          "secondary",
          "tertiary"
        ],
        [
          "!in",
          "structure",
          "bridge",
          "tunnel"
        ]
      ],
      "type": "line",
      "source": "mapbox",
      "id": "road_secondary_tertiary_casing",
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#e9ac77",
        "line-width": {
          "base": 1.2,
          "stops": [
            [
              8,
              1.5
            ],
            [
              20,
              17
            ]
          ]
        },
        "line-opacity": 1
      },
      "source-layer": "road"
    },
    {
      "interactive": true,
      "metadata": {
        "mapbox:group": "1444849345966.4436"
      },
      "id": "road_secondary_tertiary",
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#fea",
        "line-width": {
          "base": 1.2,
          "stops": [
            [
              6.5,
              0
            ],
            [
              8,
              0.5
            ],
            [
              20,
              13
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      "ref": "road_secondary_tertiary_casing"
    },
    {
      "interactive": true,
      "layout": {
        "line-join": "round"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "mapbox:group": "1444849334699.1902"
      },
      "filter": [
        "all",
        [
          "==",
          "structure",
          "bridge"
        ],
        [
          "in",
          "class",
          "secondary",
          "tertiary"
        ]
      ],
      "type": "line",
      "source": "mapbox",
      "id": "bridge_secondary_tertiary_casing",
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#e9ac77",
        "line-width": {
          "base": 1.2,
          "stops": [
            [
              8,
              1.5
            ],
            [
              20,
              17
            ]
          ]
        },
        "line-opacity": 1
      },
      "source-layer": "road"
    },
    {
      "interactive": true,
      "metadata": {
        "mapbox:group": "1444849334699.1902"
      },
      "id": "bridge_secondary_tertiary",
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#fea",
        "line-width": {
          "base": 1.2,
          "stops": [
            [
              6.5,
              0
            ],
            [
              7,
              0.5
            ],
            [
              20,
              10
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      "ref": "bridge_secondary_tertiary_casing"
    }
  ]
}
```

Applied to the "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7" vector source, I would expect a road with a bridge to look like this:

[image]

Because bridge casing and bridge are rendered after road casing and road, the line caps of the bridge casing are visible. But instead, I get the following:

[image]

I agree that this looks nicer without the line caps of the bridge casing, and it is probably what users would expect it to look, but if the implementation does strictly what the spec says, it is - at least to me - an unexpected result.

Am I missing something obvious? Can someone explain how the implementation handles z-order and if or how it differs from the spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your problem is that the line-caps are being occluded -- I think they don't have round line caps at all!

If you want your bridges to have [round line-caps](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layout-line-line-cap), you have to set `"line-cap": "round"` in the layer's layout properties.

Check out this working demo http://jsbin.com/yutewakuwa/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was missing something obvious.